# Vector string, int and dword troubles

Tags: c++

So i'm creating something and I got a pretty big problem.

```
vector<DWORD> GetChildren(int instance) {
   try {
       vector<DWORD> rtn;
       DWORD num4 = *(DWORD *)(*(DWORD *)(instance + 0x2C));
       DWORD num3 = *(DWORD *)(*(DWORD *)(instance + 0x2C) + 4);
       while (num4 != num3) {
         rtn.push_back(*(DWORD*)num4);
         num4 += 8;
       }
       return rtn;
   }
   catch (exception)
   {
      Sleep(1);
   }
   vector<DWORD> rtnn;
   return rtnn;
}

vector<DWORD> Children = GetChildren(Workspace);

rblua_getglobal(lua::lua_State, "print");
rblua_pushstring(lua::lua_State, Children);
rblua_pcall(lua::lua_State, 1, 0, 0);
```

I don't know how to convert the vector to a std::string or const char. Please help

Comment: `DWORD` is an integer, if you want to convert an integer to a string use `std::to_string`.

Comment: @GillBates I tried that, its a vector<DWORD> but this happens https://gyazo.com/14b5f8e4f0cfd99b64506a642063965e (no instance of overloaded function)

Comment: `DWORD num4 = *(DWORD *)(*(DWORD *)(instance + 0x2C));` This does not seem safe at all.

Comment: @Kevin I don't understand,the function itself works. I just can't convert vector<DWORD> to std::string or const char

Comment: `std::string myString(Children.begin(), Children.end());`

Comment: @George Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Gill Bates `DWORD` is really just an unsigned int, in C++ `int` is convertible `char` and vice versa. One of `std::string` s constructors will take two input iterators (in order to copy the contents between whatever they're pointing at) so you can pass the the iterators pointing to the start and end of a vector and the contents will effectively be copied over i.e:

```
std::vector< DWORD> Children { 66,66,67 }; // it's common practice to camel case variable names, so Children should really just be children 
std::string myString(Children.begin(), Children.end());
```